# Log into SharePoint tenant through CSOM with MFA enabled

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, office-dev-pnp, multifactor-authentication

I need to log into a SharePoint tenant using an admin account that uses MFA.

This is the code.

```
var authManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
var context = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(tenantUrl); 

// load some stuff

// this will fail with 403 Unauthorized
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

The login window does pop up for a second, but closes again immediately. I assume that it uses the cookie for my regular user (without SharePoint administration rights). The following requests that need tenant scope obviously do not work.

How can I clear the token cache so I can log in with the correct user? In the PnP PowerShell I had the same problem with `-UseWebLogin`, but there I can actually use the `ClearTokenCache` parameter and then it works. I have not yet found a similar option here, and PowerShell is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to switch to another user but authManager just grab and use the existing cache, which causes it auto login with existing account.

In fact the login window use IE as the web browser control, So you can clear the cache in **Internet Option**:

- [Internet Explorer: Delete Cached Files and Cookies](https://support.pearson.com/getsupport/s/article/Internet-Explorer-Delete-Cached-Files-and-Cookies?p=browser-usecases/browser-settings-delete-cached-files-and-cookies-ie)

Comment: Already tried that too, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try using your code like below:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
   string siteUrl = "https://<tenant-name>.sharepoint.com/sites/contosoteam"; 
   var authManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager(); 
   // This method calls a pop up window with the login page and it also prompts for the multi factor authentication code. 
   ClientContext ctx = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(siteUrl); 
   // The obtained ClientContext object can be used to connect to the SharePoint site. 
   Web web = ctx.Web; 
   ctx.Load(web, w => w.Title); 
   ctx.ExecuteQuery(); 
   Console.WriteLine("You have connected to {0} site, with Multi Factor Authentication enabled!!", web.Title); 
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this could help. My problem is that the popup window called by `GetWebLoginClientContext` does not stay open long enough to actually enter my credentials, and what you have posted concerning that is pretty much identical to my code. The part after where you actually access the context fails in my case because the user is not authorized as an admin.

Comment: Ok, check [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/sharepoint-authentication-from-c-application/m-p/488257) if it helps Or try logging out from browser and clearing cache and then try again running this code.